# Customizing the bump function

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions, exponential-function, finite-element-method

I have the standard [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) below.

$$ \Psi(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{1 - \mathrm{min}(1, x^2)}} $$

[image: Bump function]

How can I customize it to be like below:

[image: Schematics of desired customization]

## Translate and scale

I can translate and scale by:

$$ \Psi(x) = e^{1-\frac{1}{1 - \mathrm{min}(1, (x-x_0)^2)}} $$

But I don't know how to deal with the $x_0 - \delta$ to $x_0 + \delta$ range.

## Range

Is this the correct final answer?

$$ \Psi(x) = e^{1-\frac{\delta^2}{\delta^2 - \mathrm{min}(\delta^2, (x-x_0)^2)}} $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: this is a much simpler question than any topology/bump function business. It’s simple scaling and translations. So, indeed, what did you try?

Comment: If $\Psi(x)$ is your original function, then you should consider $a\Psi(bx+c)$ for suitable $a,b,c$.